# Display js Data in div Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fetch-api

I want to display data I got from this code in console log (it's in JSON) and display it inside HTML. Which method shall I use?

```
async function getAVA() {

    fetch('https://graphql.avascan.info', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        query: `
        query {
            stats {
                priceAvaxUsd
            }
        }`
        }),
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => console.log(result));
  }

  getAVA();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function getAVA() {

fetch('https://graphql.avascan.info', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: `query {stats {priceAvaxUsd}}`
    }),
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.data.stats.priceAvaxUsd;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

getAVA();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I fixed my answer

Comment: Syntax error, unexpecred token {}.this is what log showd

Comment: It works but it shows all data from console, I want to show only priceAvaxusd number.